# Why MenuItem component not work as Link in react material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I try to use popover menu which should after click on item change url and component but it not works.
I built my situation in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-surf-40p19?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am using it like this

```
<MenuItem component={Link} to="/edit">
   Zmena role
</MenuItem>
```

Problem is that after clicking nothing happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that in JSX, css is written a bit differently from the regular CSS. your style `background-color: red` should be written as `backgroundColor: "red"` I have added a link to the working version I fixed below. Pay attention to how I wrote the css in the JSX.

Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-golick-jhzcz

For extra studying: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp, https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: This wasn't the problem. This i changed after i posted it here accidentally. Anyway problem is that after you try click Role menu item nothing happend. And i need to change url without refresh to www.xxxxxxx.xx/home for example

Comment: where i should add this?

Comment: You should use routes. follow this link and let me know if you have questions. https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/routing-and-navigation-in-react-cffc26e8a389